# fread() so slow after fseek()

Tags: performance, fopen, fread, fseek

I'm trying to read a large binary file (~3GB), but it takes longer time if i start reading from specified pointer position. I don't understand why this happens and i'm asking how can i resolve this issue?

I'm giving an example code below and how i measured the elapsed time.

```
int counter = 0;
char buffer[188];
FILE * m_pPlayFilePtr = fopen("binaryFile", "rb");

//get initial time here.

while ((feof(m_pPlayFilePtr) == false) && (counter< 2150))
{
  fread(buffer, 188, 1u, m_pPlayFilePtr);
  counter++;
}

//get final time here.
```

**final time - initial time ~ 500ms**

```
int counter = 0;
char buffer[188];
FILE * m_pPlayFilePtr = fopen("binaryFile", "rb");

fseek(m_pPlayFilePtr, 188000, SEEK_SET);

//get initial time here.

while ((feof(m_pPlayFilePtr) == false) && (counter< 2150))
{
  fread(buffer, 188, 1u, m_pPlayFilePtr);
  counter++;
}

//get final time here.
```

**final time - initial time ~ 1500ms**

**EDIT 1**

I have solved the issue by changing the buffer size with **setvbuf** function.

```
setvbuf(m_pPlayFilePtr, NULL, _IOFBF,  404200);
```

Comment: It should be indicated that 188 bytes are for one packet for TS MPEG.

Comment: What OS are you using? What type of disk? And how much RAM do you have?

Comment: It's Intel Atom Z510 & 1GB RAM running vxWorks OS and uses 8GB Flash disk on-board.

Comment: That is only 400kB that you are reading. I would guess that the OS may read ahead a large part of that data when you open the file. Try starting your timer before opening the file in both cases.

Comment: Even if i put the codes after fopen line inside an infinite while loop, elapsed time doesn't change, it oscillates around 500 & 1500ms in each iteration.